# Calculating time difference between [h]:mm

Tags: excel

I've got 2 fields in Excel that are formatted as [h]:mm and I need to find the value difference between them.

For example in G2 I have 4217:11 and in I2 I have 1703:11.

I know that the answer should be 2514:00 as it is 4217 hours 11 minutes minutes 1703 hours 11 minutes, however I can't figure out how to do this in Excel.

I've tried the simple minus formula, however I get a #VALUE error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look up the DATEDIFF formula in the help, it will give you all that you need.

Comment: DATEDIF also returns value, and from what I can tell, it doesn't return the hours, or did you mean the VBA DATEDIFF?

Comment: Are you sure the cells are formated as h:mm? If you try `=hour(A1)` what do you get?

Comment: #VALUE.  They're formatted as [h]:mm

Comment: OK, it seems that for some reason that when the data is copied across, it doesn't get formatted correctly, despite having the right format option selected.  If I delete it and type it manually it works.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: If you get #value then it seems it's not h:mm. If you try to use =hour() on a "real" time you will see that it parses the hour from the cell. Maybe you need to use find() and left() and right() to parse your cell value?

Comment: and the correct answer is 2514:00 and not 2514:11.

Comment: Maybe there is a space in the value?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried `=G2-I2` and it worked fine for me ... if you're getting #VALUE error, then the data definitely isn't formatted like you think.  Likely it's being formatted as text, and it just "looks" like it's in a time format.

[image]

Comment: I think you're correct.  Do you know how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: How did you get your data into the cell?  ie I just typed: "4217:11" ... but did you import it or something? or is it another calculation ? pivot table? user entry ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a formula that rebuilds the value to what you want.
But it requires helper columns.

In J2 (or whichever is free)

```
=LEFT(G2;FIND(":";G2)-1)&":"&MID(G2;FIND(":";G2)+1;2)
```

In K2 (or whichever is free)

```
=LEFT(I2;FIND(":";I2)-1)&":"&MID(I2;FIND(":";I2)+1;2)
```

The above formulas will make text to the type of string you want.
Then in the next free column set the formating to [t]:mm as you said before and just do a `=J2-K2`

Sorry for the swedish but the formulas are above

[image]